# How to save Answers in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have to design an application in which users provide answers for a list of questions.

Below is the SQL tables structure

Question - Table which lists questions

Rating - Table which has ratings

Answers- Table which stores answers for the reputed questions.

The logic which I need is, How to save the answers (rating id and Question  id)

in a table for more than 100 questions..

Whether I need to generate loop or I can use comma separator during save process?

is there any solution?

Comment: You should really describe your problem better and what you have tried so far / what you code is

Comment: The problem is how to save the answers for 100 questions in sql ?                            

How to save in an easy way without looping ?

is there any logic?

Comment: So you can save 99 answers but not 100? What is the problem there?

Comment: Where are the answers even coming from? This is so vague that nobody can really help you

Comment: What code language is your application? if it's a .net language you can simply send a DataTable to a stored procedure as a table valued parameter, and I'm sure there are similar solutions for other client languages as well.

Comment: we are using .net ..James i need to store answers for the all the questions...For eg: questions id with rating id..in answer table for 100 questions.

Answers table:

QuetsionID         AnswersId

 QuestionNo: 1   AnswerId : 3

like wise for 100 questions..

Comment: Modify your question, you should have to mention what is your requirement?

Comment: Instead of writing in comment modify your question.

Answer (score 1):

The best way of saving multiple records into an sql server table from .Net is using a table valued parameter.

First, you need to create a user defined table type (`UDT`) in your sql server:

```
CREATE TYPE UDT_UserAnswers AS TABLE
(
   UserAnswers_UserId int,
   UserAnswers_QuestionId int,
   UserAnswers_RatingId int
)
```

Second, you need to write the procedure to accept this `UDT`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tblAnswers_Insert
(
    @UserAnswers AS dbo.UDT_UserAnswers READONLY -- Must be readonly!
)
AS

INSERT INTO Answers(UserId, QuestionId, RatingId)
SELECT UserAnswers_UserId, UserAnswers_QuestionId, UserAnswers_RatingId 
FROM @UserAnswers 

GO
```

Finally, the .Net code (using ado.net):

```cs
// create a data table
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("UserAnswers_UserId", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("UserAnswers_QuestionId", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("UserAnswers_RatingId", typeof(Int32));

// Populate the data table here


// execute the stored procedure
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("<yourConnectionStringHere>")
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("tblAnswers_Insert", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserAnswers", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = dt;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your problem. I will suggest you to Save Questions in one table with some unique PK. Then save answers (in a table of its own) which have QuestionId (PK mentioned before) as a foreign key (FK). I guess you are rating Answers soi save Ratings and add them AnswerId (PK from Answers Table) and some domain specific properties like (UserName, Rating,...).

Now I do not know what ORM or SQL access platform you use. But loop is generally not OK (transactions etc). I suggest you to send XML structure into SAVE process if you are doing this with stored procedure or similar. You can have some temp tables when you store answers when you click on gui and on save you just perform "move" of data from temp to "real" storage. There are many way, but you have not mentioned your environment.